# Cloning git repository without re downloading existing data

Tags: git

I have a git repo online that has around 30 GB of textures. And I have the same textures on my local computer. I would like my local git repo to connect with the online git repo but I don't want to push/pull that 30 GB of textures. I have those already and my internet dies if I try doing that. So is there a way to sync the two repos? Also, I don't want them to be included in .gitignore (at least not permanently) because the textures keep changing every week. Is there any way to do it!?

Comment: Have you considered LFS ? https://git-lfs.github.com/

Comment: Nope, I wasn't aware of that! I will check it out! Thanks a lot! ^^